# create formGroup dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript

i used angular-archwizard for used wizard step with *ngFor

the problem is how can i create a dynamic formGroup for each step, in the code bellow i created a single formGroup for all the steps, but i want to create for each step a dynamic formGroup

```
<aw-wizard #wizard>

   <aw-wizard-step *ngFor="let category of categories">
      <ng-template awWizardStepTitle>
         <span class="custom-title">{{category.categoryLabel}}</span>
      </ng-template>

      <sof-form [border]="false" [formGroup]="parametersForm">
      <sof-sub-form column="2">
         <ng-container *ngFor="let parameter of category.parameters | sortBy: 'order'" [ngSwitch]="parameter.type">
         <sof-form-label>{{parameter.parameterLabel}}
            <span *ngIf="parameter.control  | includes: 'required'" style="color: red">*</span>
         </sof-form-label>
         <sof-form-item style="padding-top: 6px" id="parameters">
            <sof-input [type]="'text'" formControlName="{{parameter.parameterId}}" *ngSwitchCase="'text'"></sof-input>
            <sof-input [type]="'number'" formControlName="{{parameter.parameterId}}" *ngSwitchCase="'number'"></sof-input>
            <sof-monoselect formControlName="{{parameter.parameterId}}" [mode]="'autoComplete'" [options]="parameter.valuesList" bindLabel="label"
            bindValue="value" (onSearch)="onSearchParameter($event, parameter)" *ngSwitchCase="'monoselect'"></sof-monoselect>
            <label class="switch switch-small" *ngSwitchCase="'toggle'">
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{parameter.parameterId}}" formControlName="{{parameter.parameterId}}" (change)="checkboxAction(parameter.parameterId)">
            <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
         </sof-form-item>
         </ng-container>
      </sof-sub-form>
      </sof-form>

   </aw-wizard-step>

</aw-wizard>
```

Comment: please simplify your question by removing not important tags and codes, also it would be easier to help you if you create and share stackblitz project

Comment: In general you need to create forms in an array as assign them `[formGroup]="forms[index]"` or based on category `[formGroup]="forms[category.id]"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let parameter of category.parameters | sortBy: 'order';  let i = index" [ngSwitch]="parameter.type">
<sof-form-label [formControlName]="'formControlName' + i">{{parameter.parameterLabel}}

let i = 0;
for (const item of Array) {
  this.form.addControl('formControlName' + this.i,
    new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]));
i ++;}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.